# Calculating the volume under a surface with Riemann sum

Tags: interpolation

I have a set of xyz data points. X and Y are coordinates of a regular grid of 10x10 units, Z is the independent variable.

I am trying to calculate the volume under the set of points, using Riemann sum. I have used two approaches that I expected to produce the same result, and on the contrary, produce very different results.

In the first approach I make a sum of the volumes of the prism formed by every point. In the second approach I make an interpolation function with an interpolation order of 0, and then integrate it.
Here is a MWE of the code I'm using:

```
Data = {{{230, 310}, 0.4434}, {{230, 320}, 0.5078}, {{230, 330}, 
0.6000}, {{230, 340}, 0.6430}, {{230, 350}, 0.6724}, {{230, 360}, 
0.7204}, {{230, 370}, 0.7593}, {{230, 380}, 0.7987}, {{230, 390}, 
0.8908}, {{230, 400}, 1.0175}, {{230, 410}, 1.1136}, {{230, 420}, 
1.2342}, {{230, 430}, 1.3375}, {{230, 440}, 1.4055}, {{230, 450}, 
1.3979}, {{240, 310}, 0.4593}, {{240, 320}, 0.3963}, {{240, 330}, 
0.3985}, {{240, 340}, 0.3877}, {{240, 350}, 0.4262}, {{240, 360}, 
0.4763}, {{240, 370}, 0.5465}, {{240, 380}, 0.6163}, {{240, 390}, 
0.7376}, {{240, 400}, 0.8567}, {{240, 410}, 0.9769}, {{240, 420}, 
1.1350}, {{240, 430}, 1.2960}, {{240, 440}, 1.4032}, {{240, 450}, 
1.4310}, {{250, 310}, 0.5866}, {{250, 320}, 0.4513}, {{250, 330}, 
0.3789}, {{250, 340}, 0.3360}, {{250, 350}, 0.3273}, {{250, 360}, 
0.3526}, {{250, 370}, 0.4068}, {{250, 380}, 0.4520}, {{250, 390}, 
0.5269}, {{250, 400}, 0.6071}, {{250, 410}, 0.6807}, {{250, 420}, 
0.7808}, {{250, 430}, 0.8794}, {{250, 440}, 0.9572}, {{250, 450}, 
0.9682}};

Total[Data[[All, 2]]*100]

Integrate[Interpolation[Data, InterpolationOrder -> 0][x, y], {x, 230, 250}, {y, 310, 450}]
```

The first approach yields a volume of 3377.73, and the second one of 1918.94.
Can someone explain the reason for this difference? Or which one is more appropriate for the purpose of estimating a volume?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First method includes all the boundaries.  In effect it is an estimate of the integral over $225<x<255, 305<y<455$.  Omit the lower edges and the two calculations agree.

```
Total[Select[Data, 
    230 < #[[1, 1]] <= 250 && 310 < #[[1, 2]] <= 450 &][[All, 2]]*100]

Integrate[
 Interpolation[Data, InterpolationOrder -> 0][x, y],
 {x, 230, 250}, {y, 310, 450}]

(*
1918.94
1918.94
*)
```