# Making Integrals without using mathematics own integral tool. Using rectangle formula

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, homework

When determined integrals ∫ab f (x) dx become too difficult (almost all in practice) to determine exactly, remains numerical integration. We will look at the simplest, namely the rectangle formula. Divide the integration interval [a, b] for simplicity n equal length h = (b-a) / n, giving rise to a so called partition of the interval a = x0"<"x1 ... "<"xn" = b i n smaller intervals with the length h. The idea is now to approximate the integral with all the rectangles that are formed; with the base h and the height calculated in the middle of the current small range, see formula. Calculate some integrals this way.

So not using any of Mathematicas own integral tools. It should be as a Plot with the rectangles integrals under the line aswell as the calculations. Im really stuck on this and could really use some help. I don't even know where to start. The formulas are in a picture.

[image: Formulas]

[image: Example of one integral]

Hope someone can help me I have tried to search around but can't find anything that could help me.

Comment: Possibly related to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44937/calculating-the-volume-under-a-surface-with-riemann-sum

Comment: See also: [Graphically approximating the area under a curve as a sum of rectangular regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82688/27951), [How do I color Riemann integral rectangles using conditionals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87481/27951), [Trapezoid approximation to definite integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82782/27951), [Approximation of definite integral by parabolas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83329/27951).

Comment: This demonstration does what you ask, with fairly simple code: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RiemannSums/